# Peculiar Pendulum motion

Tags: scheme, racket

I am trying to code a simple swinging pendulum by progressively rotating the image formed by combination of a line and a circle:

```
(require 2htdp/image)    
(require 2htdp/universe) 

(define ang 0)
(define x 1)

(define pend
  (underlay/xy  (line 0 250 "black")
                -10 250
                (circle 10 "solid" "green")))

(define (simple_pendulum t)       
  (when (> (abs ang) 30)
    (set! x (* x -1)))
  (set! ang (+ ang x))
  (underlay/xy  (rectangle 500 500 "solid" "white") 
                250 50
                (rotate ang pend))) ; value of ang swings between -30 to +30 ;

(animate simple_pendulum)
```

Although the pendulum moves to one side properly, it does not do so on other side. Rather, the base of pendulum swings. Where is the error and how can I correct it?

Note that I am just trying to swing pendulum from one end to another at constant speed. I know that this will not be physically accurate movement pattern of a real pendulum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that after rotation, you are instructing `underlay/xy` to draw your image in such a way that the left edge of the pendulum image is at x coordinate 250. And, as you can see, that's exactly what it's doing; as the pendulum swings to the left, the left edge of the pendulum is always at x coordinate 250.

So, how to solve it?

You should be using pinholes. Here's what I mean:

```
#lang racket
(require 2htdp/image)    
(require 2htdp/universe) 

(define ang 0)
(define x 1)

(define pend
  (put-pinhole
   10 0
  (underlay/xy  (line 0 250 "black")
                -10 250
                (circle 10 "solid" "green"))))

(define (simple_pendulum t)     
  (when (> (abs ang) 30)
    (set! x (* x -1)))
  (set! ang (+ ang x))
  (clear-pinhole
   (underlay/pinhole  (put-pinhole
                       250 100
                       (rectangle 500 500 "solid" "white")) 

                      (rotate ang pend)))) ; value of ang swings between -30 to +30 ;

(animate simple_pendulum)
```

Comment: This works perfectly! A brief description of how pinholes are working here will be very helpful.

Comment: The solitary 'pend' statement after pend function definition seem to be unnecessary.

Comment: Good point, I removed it. Re: pinholes: did you read the docs in 2htdp/image? I'd be happy to answer questions about it.

Comment: Yes, it is described very well there.